# "Recalculate" tax for imported orders

Tags: magento-1.9

We use an API service that exports products to third party marketplaces like Bol.com. Since this specific marketplace has no shipment costs all product prices are raised by €2.95. So a product of €10,00 becomes €12,95 and so on. The problem we now have is that once a sale has been made the total sales prices is set to €12,95 and when the invoice is made the tax is calculated based on the price set in Magento, which is €10,00.

The API service is not able to change anything so we should have a solution for this apparently. Is there a way the taxes are recalculated or something? Or should we take a look at a more programmatic solution?